# Android ListAdapter is not updating after delete an item

Tags: android

I'm trying to update a ListAdapter using SearchView and deleting a item, but it doesn't work.

A example:

```
1 A23-01  2015-10-11  2324  no info
2 A23-45  2015-10-11  5363  no info
3 A24-51  2015-10-15  3336  no info
4 A24-34  2015-10-15  9389  no info
5 A24-03  2015-10-17  0304  no info
```

Using SearchView, filtering "A24-":

```
3 A24-51  2015-10-15  3336  no info
4 A24-34  2015-10-15  9389  no info
5 A24-03  2015-10-17  0304  no info
```

Deleting item 4, ListAdapter is not updating. What's wrong with this code?

My code:

```
public class SuperList extends ListActivity {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listdata = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ...code omitted...

        Cursor c = db.query(tabledef, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            int ColumnasTotal = c.getColumnCount();
            while(c.moveToNext()){
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < ColumnasTotal; i++) {
                    String key = c.getColumnName(i);
                    String value = c.getString(i);
                    hm.put(key, value);
                }
            listdata.add(hm);
            }
        }

            ...code omitted...

        String[] from = { "device"   , "date"   , "number"   , "info"};
        int[]      to = { R.id.Device, R.id.Date, R.id.Number, R.id.Info };
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SuperList.this,  listdata, R.layout.activity_super_list, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);


        @Override
            protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, final int position, long id) {

            final CharSequence[] items = { "Add", "View", "Delete" };
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SuperList.this);
            builder.setTitle("¿QUE DESEA HACER?");

            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    ListAdapter adapter = getListAdapter();
                    Object userobj = adapter.getItem(position);
                    int position = listdata.indexOf(userobj);

                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    HashMap<String, String> userdata = (HashMap<String, String>) userobj;  
                    String whereClause = "Id=" + userdata.get("Id");
                    String idIncidente = listdata.get(position).get("Id");

                    switch (item) {
                    case 0:
                        // ADD
                            ...code omitted...
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // View
                        Intent explicit_intent = new Intent(SuperList.this, InfoClient.class);
                        explicit_intent.putExtra("userdata", userdata);
                        startActivity(explicit_intent);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        // Delete
                        listdata.remove(position);
                        ((SimpleAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
                        // ***********************
                        // *** WHEN DELETE A ITEM, SimpleAdapter IS NOT UPDATED USING SearchView *** //
                        // ***********************
                        break;

                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.super_list, menu);

                MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
                mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
                mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search...");
                mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
                    @Override 
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newQueryText){
                        ListAdapter adapter = SuperList.this.getListAdapter();
                        ((SimpleAdapter) adapter).getFilter().filter(newQueryText);
                        ((SimpleAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

                     return true;
                    }

                    @Override 
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query){
                         // Do nothing
                    return true;
                    }
                  }
                );
            return true;
        }
}
```

can anyone advise?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by "deleting item 4"; where and how is it deleted? And which part of your code do you expect to react to the deletion?

Comment: When I touch the item 4 in my android (using data example), appear 3 options: Add, View and Delete. I select DELETE.

Look into the code:
`// *** WHEN DELETE A ITEM, SimpleAdapter IS NOT UPDATED USING SearchView *** //` 
in `builder.setItems`, case 2.

The code working fine if Searchview is not used.